# Python 3: how to create list out of float numbers?

Tags: python

Anyone knows how can I solve this issue?
I have the following code.

```
result=[]
for i in range(len(response_i['objcontent'][0]['rowvalues'])):
    lat = response_i['objcontent'][0]['rowvalues'][i][0]
    print(lat)
    for i in lat:
        result.append(i)     
    print (result)
```

Following is the output of `print(lat)`:

```
92.213725
191.586143
228.981615
240.353291
```

and following is the output of `print(result)`:

```
['9', '2', '.', '2', '1', '3', '7', '2', '5', '1', '9', '1', '.', '5', '8',
'6', '1', '4', '3', '2', '2', '8', '.', '9', '8', '1', '6', '1', '5', '2',
'4', '0', '.', '3', '5', '3', '2', '9', '1']
```

I expected to get the output in following format:

```
[92.213725, 191.586143, 228.981615, 240.353291]
```

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, *any* time you are iterating through `range(len(something))` you are doing it wrong. Secondly why the nested iteration through `lat`? Why not just append `lat` directly?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Off-topic, but why is iterating through `range(len(something))` wrong? Sometimes I have two lists with equal lengths that I need to loop through and do things to them together. Could you explain how this can be done without `range(len(something))`?

Comment: Well I was probably being slightly hyperbolic, but in your case something like `for a, b in zip(list1, list2)`?

Comment: Iterating with `range(len(something))` is not *always* wrong but is *often* wrong.    If you wish to change the item you are iterating through, there is little choice.

Comment: @DanielRoseman That's cool for small lists, but if the lists are huge, this won't be efficient, right? I got your point though :)

Comment: `zip` is a generator in Python 3 so it's perfectly efficient. In Python 2 you can use `itertools.izip`.

Answer (score 2):

So, your error is that instead of simply adding your `latitute` to the list, you are iterating over each character of the latitude, as a string, and adding that character to a list.

```
result=[]
for value in response_i['objcontent'][0]['rowvalues']:
    lat = value[0]
    print(lat)
    result.append(float(lat))

print (result)
```

Besides that, using range(len(...))) is the way things have to be done in almost all modern languages, because they either don't implement a "for ...each" or do it in an incomplete or faulty way.

In Python, since the beginning it is a given that whenever one wants a for iteration he wants to get the items of a sequence, not its indices (for posterior retrieval of the indices). Some auxiliar built-ins come in to play to ensure you just interate the sequence: zip to mix one or more sequences, and enumerate to yield the indices as well if you need them.